# How to show image column in ultragrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'v an Ultragrid in windows form that displays data from database through a datatable.
in the datatable I have a column containing image paths I want to know how to get the ultragrid to display the image of these paths?

*Note: my Infragistic version is 5.6 and I'm working in .net 2.0*

Comment: Use OnPaint / OnRender event and paint your image using bitmap image in System.Windows.Drawing.

Comment: Aren't there a way where I can tell the Ultragrid that this column is Image and then it displays it in the correct format using the image path provided in that column?

Comment: What kind of data you have your data source. is it (Binary / Stream or just a fileName)?

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I've a column containing image path in the datatable. So the source is text (path + filename) (Ex: C:\Users\msabry\FirstTask\1.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an unbound column of Image type to your UltraGrid and to hide the column that contains the images paths. To do so you can handle InitializeLayout event like this:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    // Hide the "path" column
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Path"].Hidden = true;

    // Add new unbound column of Image type - here you will show the pictures
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add("Image").DataType = typeof(Image);
}
```

After you have "prepared" your grid to show pictures in InitializwRow event you can load each image like this:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if this is data row -  if you have summaries, groups...
    if (e.Row.IsDataRow)
    {
        // Create an image from the path string in the "Path" cell
        Image image = Bitmap.FromFile(e.Row.Cells["Path"].Text);

        // Put the image in the "Image" cell
        e.Row.Cells["Image"].Value = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Exactly what I did, but I was looking for a way where the ultragrid can understand the path column and show it directly as image rather that hiding the path column and creating another for the actual image. +1 for taking the time to write this answer.